# Analyze BigQuery data using R without downloading it or creating local copies of it

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I just started using GCP for Data Science and I'm a bit overwhelmed with all the different tools. I have customer data in BigQuery which I'd like to analyze further for customer segmentation purposes.

However, I am not allowed to download it or have any copies locally. Most of the R+BigQuery tutorials I've seen seem to do that through. I am currently looking into analyzing the data using DataLab but there I can't seem to use R, only Python.

**What would be a safe and cheap (!) way to analyze BigQuery data (< 100GBs) in R without downloading it? What GCP tool would be suited for it?** Is there a way that does not include running R code in Python?

Comment: R operates completely in memory.  The only way for you to do this from R without downloading it would be to use an API to BigQuery called from R.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about that, thanks! So using sth like this package https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery?

Comment: Yes, good find.  So then the only question is are you allowed to download result sets from queries on these Big Query tables.  Obviously, doing `SELECT *` on a BQ table is functionally the same as just downloading the entire data

Comment: but cost wise it is different - downloading data using `tabledata.list` AOI  is free whereas `SELECT *` will cost full table scan :o)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Yes that's a problem - that I could just do SELECT * and get the data. Don't think the entity providing me with the data would like that. So I guess the best way is to run R on a VM in the cloud and do the processing "in memory" there.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant indeed SELECT * would be a bad idea with a large table :)

Comment: Yes, doing this in the cloud, where you have things like security, seems safer for your situation.

Comment: What is the analysis that you want to do?  BigQuery isn't just a data-store, it's an analysis engine -- you should try to do your analysis *in* BigQuery and then just pull down "small" results to R for final visualization, etc.  (Also, I second the recommendation that you use bigrquery -- dplyr is also worth looking at.)